# slurmdbd fails to start (initial installation)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, slurm

I tried to install `slurmdbd` for accounting on a Ubuntu 16.04 from the standard repositories (version: `15.08.7-1build1`).

Here are the commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
$ sudo mysql
> create user 'slurm'@'localhost' identified by '123456';
> grant all on *.* TO 'slurm'@'localhost' identified by '123456' with grant option;
> create database slurm_acct_db;
> flush privileges;
> exit
$ sudo apt-get install slurmdbd
$ sudo vi /etc/slurm-llnl/slurmdbd.conf
$ cat /etc/slurm-llnl/slurmdbd.conf
AuthType=auth/munge
AuthInfo=/var/run/munge/munge.socket.2
DbdHost=localhost
DebugLevel=debug5
StorageHost=localhost
StorageLoc=slurm_acct_db
StoragePass=123456
StorageType=accounting_storage/mysql
StorageUser=slurm
LogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmdbd.log
PidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmdbd.pid
SlurmUser=slurm
```

However starting `slurmdbd` fails:

```
$ sudo systemctl start slurmdbd.service
Job for slurmdbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status slurmdbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
$ systemctl status slurmdbd.service
● slurmdbd.service - Slurm DBD accounting daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmdbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Di 2018-02-06 08:42:59 CET; 21s ago
  Process: 5881 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmdbd $SLURMDBD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 06 08:42:59 accslurm systemd[1]: Starting Slurm DBD accounting daemon...
Feb 06 08:42:59 accslurm systemd[1]: slurmdbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 06 08:42:59 accslurm systemd[1]: Failed to start Slurm DBD accounting daemon.
Feb 06 08:42:59 accslurm systemd[1]: slurmdbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 06 08:42:59 accslurm systemd[1]: slurmdbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
$ journalctl -xe
Feb 06 08:42:59 accslurm systemd[1]: Starting Slurm DBD accounting daemon...
-- Subject: Unit slurmdbd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit slurmdbd.service has begun starting up.
Feb 06 08:42:59 accslurm systemd[1]: slurmdbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 06 08:42:59 accslurm systemd[1]: Failed to start Slurm DBD accounting daemon.
-- Subject: Unit slurmdbd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit slurmdbd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

Trying to do so manually with verbose output:

```
$ sudo -u slurm slurmdbd -Dvvv
slurmdbd: error: mysql_query failed: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ignore table cluster_table modify `creation_time` int unsigned not null, modify ' at line 1
alter ignore table cluster_table modify `creation_time` int unsigned not null, modify `mod_time` int unsigned default 0 not null, modify `deleted` tinyint default 0, modify `name` tinytext not null, modify `control_host` tinytext not null default '', modify `control_port` int unsigned not null default 0, modify `last_port` int unsigned not null default 0, modify `rpc_version` smallint unsigned not null default 0, modify `classification` smallint unsigned default 0, modify `dimensions` smallint unsigned default 1, modify `plugin_id_select` smallint unsigned default 0, modify `flags` int unsigned default 0, drop primary key, add primary key (name(20));
slurmdbd: Accounting storage MYSQL plugin failed
slurmdbd: error: Couldn't load specified plugin name for accounting_storage/mysql: Plugin init() callback failed
slurmdbd: error: cannot create accounting_storage context for accounting_storage/mysql
slurmdbd: fatal: Unable to initialize accounting_storage/mysql accounting storage plugin
```

So it seems there is an error in the syntax for the creation of the database?

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether it's supposed to be resolved by manually downgrading to older mysql version or by tweaking slurmdbd. But the root cause is that `alter ignore table` has been [removed from mysql 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7395). It looks like you use "old syntax" SQL statements with a "new syntax" engine.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I installed 5.6 from 14.04 for now, which works but isn't a great solution: `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe'; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6`